# laravel 5.4 menu login register still shown after login user

Tags: php, web, menu, navbar, laravel-5.4

I have this problems for a long time, I am using laravel 5.4 to develop a programs but i get stuck with this problem.
When i try Login use Laravel make:auth to the web its redirect me to the /home and the menu in navbar is change correct? But when i push back button or i go to the index page in route '/' or "localhost:8000" the login and register menu is displaying again. Do you have some clue?

After Login
[image: This is page after login]

This is when i go to route
[image: This is when i go to route /]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is that you can see in the welcome.blade.php for fresh install of laravel 5.4

```
@if (Route::has('login'))
    <div class="top-right links">
      @if (Auth::check())
        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
      @else
        <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
        <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
      @endif
    </div>
@endif
```

This code checks if a route named login exists firstly (which become added automatically when php artisan make:auth is used), then checks if a user is logged in, if so, it shows home menu otherwise login and register menu. You might be deleted these if statements.